# Why don't files from Xbox 360 show up when USB drive is plugged into computer?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I'm using a Lexar JumpDrive S73 32GB USB flash drive. I've configured it on my Xbox 360 and got a message saying it's compatible and meets the standards, but when I plug in it in my computer no files show up, even in Horizon.

After the driver was installed, both the USB mass storage and Lexar JumpDrive USB device were ready to use (installed properly), but it said no driver found for Xbox 360.

I tried looking for some sort of driver (which sounds silly) but I couldn't find anything.

I'm attempting to mod Minecraft on my Xbox and I don't want to buy another USB.

Comment: Horizon is something new to me, and apparently some type of Xbox 360 file explorer/utility program.  I saw some procedures given [on this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK1CpJ_F_6U) but I don't have Minecraft so I can't help further...

Comment: If you don't end up getting an answer here, you might try on the [Horizon forums](http://www.xboxmb.com/forum/20-horizon-support/) - they might be a bit better suited to assist in this case.

Comment: So, you probably know this, but I think it should be noted that anything related to using this tool probably violates the Xbox LIVE Code of Conduct.

Answer (score 3):

When you formatted the USB using the xbox it configured it in such a way that a PC can no longer read or access the files, this happens with many devices including PVR's

Comment: Additionally, the max size of the Xbox/USB file system is 16gb. When a USB drive is formatted on an Xbox and then plugged into a windows machine you typically see files called Data0000, Data0001, etc. These files have no extension, and are 1gb in size. The only program I have seen/used to read/write this data is Horizon.

Answer (score 3):

The files on your flash drive are most likely hidden. Try clicking on the "Organize" button on the upper left corner of Windows Explorer and go to "Folder and search options". Click on the "View" tab and check the "show hidden files, folders and drives" radio button.

Comment: This is not useful if you are using windows 7 and up.

Comment: @oldhairy It changed in windows 7 and up, but you still can go to folder options and check that button.

Answer (score 0):

The files are hidden and a PC won't see them.  Horizon, which I have tried with some success, does see the files and would WOULD allow you to edit them IF you pay horizon money to upgrade a subscription.  , pay enough for Xbox live so Horizon is not what I'd prefer, and I'm sure you don't want to pay either.