# My computer says my USB stick containing my borderlands character is empty

Tags: borderlands-2

I am trying to edit my Borderlands 2 character save from my Xbox 360 but my computer says the USB contains no files. I have tried multiple different USBs and multiple different game saves from different games. My computer refuses to acknowledge that there are files on the USB.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, is there a process I have to go through in order for my computer to be able to read the game save or has Xbox found a way to stop save editing all together?

Comment: See here, [why-dont-files-from-xbox-360-show-up](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89738/why-dont-files-from-xbox-360-show-up-when-usb-drive-is-plugged-into-computer)

Comment: It's been done with [Skyrim Saves](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mfgrp/psa_you_can_transfer_skyrim_savegame_files_from/)

Comment: I'm trying that now

Comment: Not sure if modifying is supported on here though. Question may get removed. Backing it up... Well.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is bump my character up a few levels because i'm stuck and i can't get out of the place I'm in

Comment: @Brok3n Why would you think that modding a save file would not be supported by the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see the files, because they are a hidden folder.
If you go to folder settings and then there is a tab containing options to show all files or to hide/unhide system files.
If you don't know what your doing, I don't reccomend it, as showing hidden files in your drive may mean you might accidentally delete or move or even give access to those files. Meaning your computer could become unusable without a repair disk or Windows disk.